# How to pass `chromeDriver` value dynamically in conf.js?

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am using Protractor to write tests for my application and to run all the tests on Chrome, I need to use `chromedriver`. The `chromedriver` file depends on os specification.

In my test project, I created a folder like this

```
 -- browser-drivers
   -- chrome
    -- linux
     -- x32
      -- chromedriver
     -- x64
      -- chromedriver 
    -- windows
     -- x32
      -- chromedriver
     -- x64
      -- chromedriver
```

I want to pass the value in `conf.js` in automatic way so that it will pick correct version of `chromedriver` as per the Os specification. As of now it is hard coded like this:

```
chromeDriver: './browser-drivers/chrome/linux/64bits/chromedriver'
```

So next if I am setting this project on any other Os, I dont want to change `conf.js`, it should be able to pick correct version of `chromedriver`.

Comment: it worked for me: `var os = require('os');
var osPlatform = os.platform();
var osBits = os.arch();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var os = require('os'); 
var osPlatform = os.platform(); 
var osBits = os.arch()

chromeDriver: './browser-drivers/chrome/' + osPlatform + '/' + osBits + '/chromedriver'
```

It worked for me.